# Can a dictionary<ulong,Tuple<ulong,object>> have one key many values?

Tags: c#, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary with developers and studios , as `dictionary<devid,Tuple<developer,Studio>>` where `devid` is the ID, developer and studios are `objectd`.

Can this dictionaty have more than one tuple associated to the key? Eg

```
devid 12345 Developer 1 studio 1
devid 12345 Deveoper 1 studio 2
```

Devid always corresponds to the same developer. So can key 12345 correspond to both studio 1 and studio 2 as different records by adding to this dictionary or can 1 key only have one combination of developer and studio?

Comment: Think of ways you could make `Tuple<ulong, object>` into many. Hint: arrays and lists are good ways of storing multiple items.

Comment: Why not declare it as `Dictionary<ulong, List<Tuple<ulong, Object>>>` then? Now eack `ulong` key corresponds to a collection (i.e. *many*) tuples.

Comment: Could you be looking for [NameValueCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001108/namevaluecollection-vs-dictionarystring-string), which allows duplicate keys?

Answer (score 1):

You can use sample test case i have written for your purpose:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<long, List<Tuple<object, Object>>> testDict = new Dictionary<long, List<Tuple<object, Object>>>();
            testDict.Add(12345 , new List<Tuple<object, object>>(){ 
                new Tuple<object, object>("developer1", "studio1"), 
                new Tuple<object, object>("developer1", "studio2"), 
                new Tuple<object, object>("developer1", "studio3") 
            });

            foreach (KeyValuePair<long, List<Tuple<object, Object>>> kvp in testDict)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
                foreach(Tuple<object, Object> tuple in kvp.Value)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Item1 = {0}, Item2 = {1}", tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No, it can't.
The mentioned NameValueCollection does not quite suits you, 'cause it represents a collection of  pares. So you need either `Dictionary<ulong, List<Tuple<ulong, object>>` or even `Dictionary<ulong, Dictionary<ulong, object>>`