# using key/value collection in session

Tags: c#, .net, session, session-variables

Question: What is a good datatype to keep in session for a large collection of keys and values to frequently reference and update?

Application:
Updating an old .NET web app with a million pages and grids to have all the grids maintain their sort. They currently access helper code to format themselves graphically on load and on sort. I figured I could add to that code to check for a key based on the page and grid id in a collection in session to see if it has a previous expression on load. and the on sort update/add its appropriate item in the collection.

Thoughts?

[Dictionary vs NameValueCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617443/idictionarystring-string-or-namevaluecollection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) works

Comment: cool thanks! I found a helpful question on SO comparing what i thought to be my best options which confirmed your answer. I added it to the question.